# Use parameter in like clause in oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm trying to build a search page in ASP.NET that allows me to search for table names in oracle.  When I place the sql in the sqldatasource control it doesn't recognize the parameter :Tablename.  How do I need to rewrite this so that it works?

```
SELECT Owner, Table_name, Num_Rows, Tablespace_name
FROM all_tables
WHERE trim(upper(table_name)) LIKE trim(upper('%:TableName%'))
```

Comment: Um, why are you TRIMming an expression that obviously has no leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: I guess it's become a habit.  I've encountered text and date fields in our database with spaces appended to them.....you can't match them without the trim function.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Can you replace

`'%:TableName%'`

with

`'%' || :TableName || '%'`

?

Comment: Oracle is case sensitive btw. :)

Comment: Thanks ,saved a lot of time.Worked !!

Answer (score 1):

For those that might be interested:  For SQL Server embedding the % into the parameter's text like this works: (The other method described above doesn't)

```
WHERE trim(upper(table_name)) LIKE trim(upper(@TableName))
```